# Mongodb will not restart after doing a db.copyDatabase() command

Tags: mongodb

I executed a `db.copyDatabase()` command in mongo and  ran out of disk space. Now mongo won't restart.  I am running mongo on AWS.   Since the data in the new database is just a copy, would it be OK to go to the dbpath and delete the files associated with the new database and then restart mongo or would this corrupt things even more?

The files in question end in `datasetCopy.0`, `datasetCopy.1`, `datasetCopy.2`, and there is one `datasetCopy.ns` file .

Comment: Make sure that data set still exists, potentially copy/ dump that out to something external, and poke it with a separate machine, I don't really feel super comfortable telling people to delete things without looking more closely.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get mongo back up again.   Below are the steps that I took. Please keep in mind that the data from the copied database was redundant and could be removed without causing data loss so this is a very specific case. Also our database is readonly which may make it less dangerous to do this..

Using the Amazon AWS Console:

- created a snapshot of the volume where the mongodb data is stored for backup.
- removed the data files associated with the copied database. These files are named:  datasetCopy.0, datasetCopy.1, ..., datasetCopy.ns
  -- did this very carefully to make sure that I didn't accidentally delete the wrong file.
- restarted the mongod service with the command:   service mongod restart

It worked!  I made another snapshot of the volume after restarting for backup.